# SD card unexpectedly removed

Tags: sd-card, hardware

Here is my issue. I was moving data (photos and videos) from my smartphone's inner memory over to my Micro SD card with 16 GB of memory, a close-to-daily process in which I've never encountered any difficulties, when, without any warning, a notification signalling "SD card unexpectedly removed" appeared. After that, all the data previously stored on my SD card was inaccessibile from my phone, everything just disappeared, from Gallery content, to music, to apps. I tried to restart my phone, which is a Samsung Galaxy A3 from 2015, multiple consecutive times, but nothing changed, except that after a few attempts the notification had changed to "Preparation of SD card. Checking for errors". I also tried to access the SD card by connecting the phone to my laptop via USB, but it led to nothing. It's as though the SD card isn't in fact inside its socket, although I took it out several times to clean it up and check for cracks or any type of damage, which is not the case. 
What should I do? Is there any way I can retrieve my data, even with the aid of a programme?
I apologise in advance if the notifications texts I've provided do not correspond precisely to the real ones, as my phone's system's language is not English. 
Thank you for your availability.

Comment: SD cards use flash memory, it has a finite life span... The card could just be done. Can you insert it into a card reader on a computer and see if it is recognized?

Comment: This topic has been done to death here. Use photorec to recover what data you can